# how to verify the trust path to a gpg key?

Tags: cryptography, public-key-encryption, gnupg, pgp

I want to check whether the gpg key used by Julien Danjou for his [emacs snapshot repository](http://emacs.naquadah.org) can be trusted. There are many [trust paths from my key to Juliens key](http://pgp.cs.uu.nl/mk_path.cgi?FROM=042BA65A&TO=8B78A5C2&PATHS=trust+paths). But I can't believe that there shouldn't be any gpg command which just answers this simple question from my local keyring. Or is there?

Apparently I'm not the only one [having this problem](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~davide/howto/validate_gpg.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right to be concerned; that Julien Danjou guy is slippery. (Kidding!)

I believe you're looking for this command:

```
gpg --list-keys --list-options show-uid-validity 8B78A5C2
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use pathfinder sites like [Henk P. Penning's pathfinder](http://pgp.cs.uu.nl/), although they need you to push the keys to specific keyservers.

There's also the [sigtrace tool](http://www.chaosreigns.com/code/sigtrace/), but that one requires that you import all the intermediate keys in your keyring, which can generate quite a lot of noise.